# Creating transparent mask for Meta AI Segment Anything (SAM) segmentations in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Because the original color of the segmentations are important to retain, I would like to have a transparent segmentation mask with Meta AI's Segment Anything (SAM).

```
sv.MaskAnnotator(color=sv.Color.xyz)
```

With the code above, a color or color code can be specified, but how can I make it completely transparent (or otherwise in such a way that the original colors are retained)?

I use bounding boxes by YOLOv8 as input for the Segment Anything model

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import supervision as sv
from jupyter_bbox_widget import BBoxWidget

widget = BBoxWidget()

#default_box is going to be used if you will not draw any box on image above
default_box = {'x': 68, 'y': 247, 'width': 555, 'height': 678, 'label': ''}

mask_predictor = SamPredictor(sam)

for image in yolo_test_data:
    box = widget.bboxes[0] if widget.bboxes else default_box
    box = yolo_convertor(image['tensor'])[0]

    image_bgr = cv2.imread(image['image_path'])
    image_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    mask_predictor.set_image(image_rgb)

    masks, scores, logits = mask_predictor.predict(
        box=box,
        multimask_output=True
    )
    
    mask_annotator = sv.MaskAnnotator(color=sv.Color.red())

    detections = sv.Detections(
        xyxy=sv.mask_to_xyxy(masks=masks),
        mask=masks
    )
   
    detections2 = detections[detections.area == np.max(detections.area)]

    segmented_image = mask_annotator.annotate(scene=image_bgr.copy(), detections=detections2)

    # Save image to google drive
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join("/content/drive/MyDrive/xxx/xxx", os.path.basename(image['image_path'])), segmented_image)
```